# Prove Faculty Determinant

Tags: matrices

so I got this following task from my professor: n element N Matrix An = (aij) element M^nxn(K) with

aij = 1 if i = j

-j if i = j + 1

i if i = j - 1

0 for the rest

I must determine the determinants for A1 A2 and A3 Then make an assumption for det(An) and prove it with induction

My own thoughts:

A1 
det = 1

A2
det = 2

A3
det = 3

An
det = faculty/ n!

Correct me if my thoughts are wrong.. and thanks for reading this thread.. I would appreciate if you give me a hint for the induction too if my thoughts are right and I think they are right.. I just have to prove my assumption with the induction now.. and I'm stuck at the Induction step with the
n+1 x n+1 Matrix..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: why do you call this a "faculty" determinant?  And "faculty" / $n!$?

Comment: Because the determinant is calculated that way.. 1*2*3..etc.. short version n!.. thanks for the tutorial I will try to understand it later